# Vagrant up error (default: Box 'boxcutter/ubuntu1510' could not be found)

Tags: vagrant

Hello I'm a newbie who just set up the VM and vagrant on my windows 10.
When I tried to `vagrant up` in command prompt, the following message was shown.

[image]

I don't know anything about Vagrant or Box, but I just want to start learning Ruby...
would anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

`Box could not be found`. It's means that box in `localhost.vm.box` named incorrectly. Try install default ubuntu box:

```
localhost.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
```

...or select another box name.

Comment: Box exists so op will probably have same issue with another box

Answer (score 0):

That is weird, the box should be available, its at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxcutter/boxes/ubuntu1510 in atlas

try to download the box first : `vagrant box add boxcutter/ubuntu1510` then `vagrant up`

If that does not work you can try to download the box file directly from https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxcutter/boxes/ubuntu1510/versions/2.0.16/providers/virtualbox.box and add the box to vagrant `vagrant box add boxcutter/ubuntu1510 <path of the downloaded box file>`